# How to find direct children which contain nodes with specified text with xpath?

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

I need to extract all children which have nodes with some text. Html structure might be the following:

```
<div>
  <div>
    A
  </div>
  <p>
    <b>A</b>
  </p>
  <span>
    B
  </span>
</div>
```

I need to extract child nodes which have "A" text. It should return `div` and `p` nodes

I tried the following xpaths:

```
./*/*[contains(text(), 'A')]
./*/*[./*[contains(text(), 'A')]]
```

but the first one returns only `div` with "A" text and the second one returns only `p` with "A" text

Is it possible to construct xpath which will return both children?

Node containing "A" text might be at any level in the child node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need XPath that returns both child nodes, try to use

```
./*/*[contains(., "A")]
```

Comment: I found `./*/*[contains(text(), 'A') or .//*[contains(text(), 'A')]]` which works also but your looks much nicer

Answer (score 0):

I suspect contains() is wrong here, unless you really want to select a node whose value is "HAT" as well as one whose value is "A".

Try

```
*/*[normalize-space(.)='A']
```

Comment: I also want to select nodes whose value is HAT. Thank you for the help!